# How can I count the values of these cards

Tags: php

I'm working on a very small blackjack game in PHP.

I'm currently writing the function to count the cards, but the aces are kicking my butt.

My cards are all in an array like this:

```
$card_array = array( "ca", "c10", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9",
    "cj", "ck", "cq", "da", "d10", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8",
    "d9", "dj", "dk", "dq", "ha", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9",
    "hj", "hk", "hq", "sa", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8", "s9",
    "s10", "sj", "sk", "sq");`
```

Where the first character is the suit and everything after that is the card (j for jack, etc)

Here's what I have for counting the values up so far:

```
function bj_calculate_values( $cards ) {
    $card_values = 0;
    foreach ($cards as $card) {
        if (substr($card, 1) == "k" || substr($card, 1) == "q" || substr($card, 1) == "j") {
            $card_values += 10;
        }
        else if (substr($card, 1) != "a") {
            $card_values += substr($card, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Originally, I also had the ace in there valued at 11, but obviously that would cause problems. I feel like I need to keep relooping to make sure the aces don't put us over 21, but I'm not entirely sure of the best way to go about doing that.

I'd appreciate some input, guys.
**EDIT**:

The best I can think of is adding this to the function

```
foreach ($cards as $card) {
    if (substr($card, 1) == "a") {
        if ($card_values + 11 <= 21) {
            $card_values += 11;
        }
        else {
            $card_values += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Actually I think this might work. Give me a few minutes to test.

**EDIT:**

Nope, didn't work. 4, ace, ace, 6 came out to 22 with this.

Comment: No, not homework. Just a personal project to try to expand on my own skills. I wish my school offered web development. :(

Comment: If you just need to make sure you are not over 21, count each Ace as 1 point. It will essentially be the "minimum sum" of the card values. Counting each Ace as 11 would be the "maximum sum".

Comment: what @showdev said, otherwise would need to explicitly know if ace is 11 or 1 when doing count.  i.e. total is 8 or 18?

Comment: Right, but in that case if it wasn't over 21, I'd need to go back and recount the aces as 11...which...might be doable efficiently. I suppose if I add 10 for each ace afterwards until > 21?

Comment: @Rob: Can you elaborate more? Are you stepping through each card trying to get as close to 21 as possible without going over? Are used cards discarded until another 'reshuffle'?

Comment: @showdev ah right that's a good point. But how would I go about doing it when doing the final count to compare their hand to the house's hand?

Comment: @Rob My suggestion only determines if the user "busted". The user can choose whether they want each Ace counted as 1 or 11, right? How do they make this choice in your scenario?

Comment: @MikePurcell Yes. Trying to get as close to 21 as possible without going over. There's no reshuffle for this. I'm kind of cheating for now by using "multiple decks" in case the same card shows up multiple times. At a later time, I'll likely start pulling them out until the next hand (essentially shuffling after each hand)

Comment: @showdev Here, they'll either 'hit' or 'stand'. If they 'stand', then I'll just have to count and assume for the highest possible value <= 21. This of course means I'll have to account for multiple aces, as well, if they indeed have more than one ace

Comment: Can you post all the code? I'm curious at how many cards you pass in. I assume there is a loop somewhere which will pass in 2 random array elements, then if < 21, pass in another card and so on?

Comment: @MikePurcell Right now the code is very small. I haven't done any checks yet. About to move on to the 'hit' function, but I need to make sure the cards can be counted first. For now all I'm doing is pulling two cards at random for the house and two cards at random for the player from the `$card_array`

Comment: @Rob: If you are only dealing with two cards, the most it can be is 21, you can never go over, so why not just include a substr where the first char is a and just add 11? There should be logic before the 'hit' logic to check the total value returned from your function, if total value >= 16 and <=21 stand, else hit.

Comment: @MikePurcell Because the player will have his own option to hit or stand. After the initial deal, if he hits, I need to recount. If he hits again, I need to recount.

Comment: just made an edit. sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know much about BlackJack, but this is my try.

```
    function bj_calculate_values( $cards ) {
        $card_values = 0;
        $ace = 0;
        foreach ($cards as $card) {
            $val = substr($card, 1);
            if (!is_numeric($val))
            {
                    if ('a' == $val)
                    {
                            $val = 0;
                            $ace ++;
                    }
                    else
                            $val = 10;
            }
            $card_values    += $val;
        }
        while ($ace)
            $card_values += ($card_values + 11*$ace-- <= 21) ? 11: 1;


        return $card_values;
    }
```

### UPDATE

If I understand your other comment, you want 6 4 A A A to come out 13, 6 4 A A to come out 12, and 6 4 A to come out 21. So the number of *remaining* aces count. Modified the source accordingly.

### Explanation

First of all we calculate the value of non-ace cards. These are constant, so we get it over with. And this total is the (preliminary) `$card_values`.

Then we may have (or not) some aces. It makes sense to have a `while($aces)` so that if we have no aces, we do nothing.

And now the question is, what do we do with those aces? Here is where your requisite comes in: the sum must fit into 21. This means that I can't just say "I'm at 10, I have an ace, so it fits into 21" because there might be *another* ace after that. So I have to calculate what would the *worst* case be if I were to add in all remaining aces; and that's of course the number of aces, times 11. While the worst case is still good (i.e., `$card_values + 11*$ace` is less than 21) I can add 11. While it is not, I have to add 1.

It is a form of "greedy" algorithm: I fit in all the 1's we can, while ensuring enough 11's are left to reach the closest approach to 21 that does not exceed.

I seem to remember (I might be wrong, heh) that there was a nasty bug in this implementation which will come out whenever NumberOfItems * LowestValue >= HighestValue (I'm not too sure about that "equals" though). But in this case, it would require NumberOfItems to be above 11/1 = 11 aces, and there are not so many aces in the deck, so we're cool. And to be sure, the possible cases are five - from "no" to "four" aces in a hand - and easily tested for all sums of other cards:

```
    // J Q K are worth 10, so we can use 10 instead.
    // And a fake card with value of 0 stands for "nothing".
    // We use the suit of Klingon, with up to four identical aces :-D

    for ($first = 0; $first <= 21; $first++)
    {
        $hand = array("k$first");
        for ($aces = 1; $aces < 5; $aces++)
        {
            $hand[] = "ka";
            $value  = bj_calculate_values($hand);

            // Let us ponder the possible values of $value.

            if ($value <= 11)
            {
                    // This is an error: we could have gotten closer to 21
                    // by upvaluing an ace. A correct implementation will
                    // never enter here except in the case of a LONE ACE.
                    if (($first != 0) || ($aces != 1))
                        print "ERROR: " . implode(" ", $hand) . " = $value\n";
            }
            // We have a value from 12 to 21.
            // Could we have done better? What cards do we have?
            // If no aces, of course no. All card values are then fixed.

            // If at least one ace, interpreted as 11, again not:
            // cannot interpret it above 11, and interpret as 1 would LESSEN the score.

            // If at least one ace, interpreted as 1, were we to interpret it
            // as 11, we would be summing 10. And 12 would become 22, and blow.

            // So, from 12 to 21, the result MUST be correct.

            // Finally, $value more than 21.
            if ($value > 21)
            {
                   // This is admissible ONLY if we could have done no better, which
                   // means $value is given by the fixed cards' value, $first, plus 
                   // ALL ACES COUNTED AS ONES.
                   if ($value != ($first + $aces))
                        print "ERROR: " . implode(" ", $hand) . " = $value\n";
             }
        }
    }
```

The output (version 1)

```
VERIFY: k0 ka = 11              Correct, we had a lone ace and gave it 11.
VERIFY: k18 ka ka ka ka = 22    Correct, we had 18 in other cards and all A's to 1's.
VERIFY: k19 ka ka ka = 22       Ditto, 19 in cards.
VERIFY: k19 ka ka ka ka = 23    Ditto, 19 in cards.
...                             ...
```

Current output (added code to only print errors):

```
-- nothing :-)
```

Comment: Well done. It works perfectly, although I'm not entirely sure how. Can you explain that while loop a bit, please?

Comment: There is one issue with the calculation. If an ace had a value of 11, but if the following cards result in a total > 21, then the ace needs to take a value of 1 so the user doesn't bust. For example; A, 6, A, 10. Before the 10 the user had 11, 6, 1 for a total of 18, but the 10 pushed the user to 28, so the first ace must now take a value of 1 so the user has 18.

Comment: @MikePurcell when I run this function it does indeed come out to 18. Are you getting something else?

Comment: @Rob: Disregard. Looks like the logic gives no regards to order aces appeared, which is correct. It is taking the value of all non-aces and comparing it with the number of aces found. If the number is > 21, the ace becomes a 1.+1

Comment: @Rob, I added an explanation of the loop -- turned out I can use it for a thing I'm working on, and you stand to profit from that :-D

Comment: Great explanation, and I completely understand now. Thanks a lot, man! Wish I could give more upvotes